# maven-enforcer-plugin complains about dependencies that I cannot find in pom.xml files

Tags: maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

I am encountering a problem with the maven-enforcer-plugin. It is complaining with the following (simplified) output:

```
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability the error(s) are [
Dependency convergence error for com.company.project:interfaces:1.0.4 paths to dependency are:
+-com.company.project:product:1.0.14-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.company.project:some_part_A:1.0.0
    +-com.company.project:interfaces:1.0.4
and
+-com.company.project:product:1.0.14-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.company.project:some_part_B:1.0.0
    +-com.company.project:some_sub_part_BB:1.1.0
      +-com.company.project:interfaces:1.0.4
and
+-com.company.project:product:1.0.14-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.company.project:interfaces:1.0.6
```

The problem is with `some_sub_part_BB:1.1.0`. According to the plugin, this part has a dependency on version 1.0.4 of the interfaces. But this is not possible: version 1.0.0 of `some_sub_part_BB` used interfaces version 1.0.3, and version 1.1.0 of `some_sub_part_BB` went directly to using interfaces version 1.0.6. I do not have any artifacts of `some_sub_part_BB` that uses version 1.0.4.

I guess I'm looking at some bug of the plugin, but I would like to debug this issue to make sure what is going wrong. Is this an issue anyone has encountered before, or can someone provide me any pointers on how to debug this problem? (I am fairly new to Maven, and aside from checking all the pom.xml files I have no idea where to look further).

---

Side note: The idea is (was) that the interface version to be used is specified on the project level POM, so that all (sub-) parts agree on which interface to use. However, as you can see, the different parts also specify which interface they use, which I don't think is the correct way of doing this. I haven't figured out how to fix this (yet).

Comment: Show us your `mvn dependency:tree`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is not a bug: in the pom.xml file, you can overrule versions of artifacts in the section `dependencyManagement`. In my case, someone enforced version 1.0.4 of the interfaces. The enforcer plugin does not show this; it only became apparent to me after generating the dependency tree with the verbose flag, i.e. `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`.